# npm package fails to install "npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, remote-access

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.4.0+
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "lodash"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path /root/test/node_modules/.staging/lodash-9a2aabe2
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/root/test/node_modules/.staging/lodash-9a2aabe2' -> '/root/test/node_modules/lodash'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/action/finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/root/test/node_modules/.staging/lodash-9a2aabe2' -> '/root/test/node_modules/lodash'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/root/test/node_modules/.staging/lodash-9a2aabe2' -> '/root/test/node_modules/lodash']
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/test/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

Install using this command

```
sudo npm install -g <package name> --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: Note that this no longer works with npm 7+ https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v7.11.1/CHANGELOG.md#all-lifecycle-scripts

Answer (score 1):

For my case i run following command

```bash
sudo npm install -g <package name> --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case i run following command, for this permission denied issue:

1st:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

2nd:

```
npm install -g npm@8.12.1
```

3rd:
check version:

```
ng version
```

Answer (score -1):

install the npm package locally for your user, and if you have to install it globally, use sudo. e.g:

`sudo npm install package -g`