# How can I install NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

After writing `npm install -g npm` I get:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marc/.npm/_logs/2021-12-13T16_06_54_229Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm package fails to install "npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790430/npm-package-fails-to-install-npm-err-error-eacces-permission-denied)

Comment: Did you read the output?

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission issue. If you are on Mac, use:

```
sudo npm install (whatever your package name is)
```

and then it will prompt you to type in your password to your computer. Doing this will fix it.

If you are not on Mac, I would find the equivalent of `sudo` for that.